# Adding html.actionLink to Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

want to add HTML.actionlink to Jquery Datatable.

Am wokrking on this existing site made by someone else. For adding data they used Jquery Datatable with is new to me.

This is the data table:

```
             this.oUserList = $('#UserList').dataTable({
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bSort": true,
                "bRetreive": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetUsers","Users")",
                "sAjaxDataProp": "Result",
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": function(source, type, val) {
                        return source.FirstName + ' ' + source.LastName;
                    }, "bSortable": true },
                    { (1st column },
                    { 2ndcolumn},
                    {
                        3rd column
                        }, "bSortable": false },
                    {
                        4th column
                        }, "bSortable": false
                    },
                    {
                        5th column
                        }, "bSortable": false
                    },
```

Here is where i want to change it to action link

```
                    { (6th)
                        "mDataProp": function (source, type, val) {
                            return M2.JsonDateToString(source.DateLastLogin);
                        }, "bSortable": false
                    },
```

My 6th column is a duplicate of the 5th, but what i need here is an action link, like this: (How i normally implement them):

```
  <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit Roles", "Edit", "Users", new { userName = "User\\" + u.UserName }, new { @class = "action" }) </td>
```

So what I want to no is how do you add a html actionLink to a Jquery Datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the source json object to build the anchor:

this should work

```
{ 
   "mDataProp": function (source, type, val) {
          return '<a href="/Home/Edit/'+source.UserName+'">Edit Roles</a>'

   }, "bSortable": false
},
```

Comment: hmm is there no way to use @Html.ActionLink or Url.Action. rather than a a tag?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you shouldn't  mix js with server side anyway.
There are a lot of reasons why you shouldn't mix them up. For example, If you want to mimify  your code, you couldn't or you'd have a hard time doing it.

Comment: If you need your link to be dynamic , why don't you add it to the json?

Answer (score 1):

Use this article www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part